# Collect Feedback workflow still sending email notification for over due items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-email, workflow-tasks-list

We have users complaining they are still receiving emails from Collect Feedback Workflow which was cancelled while ago. Here is the situation, Collect Feedback is one of many workflow associated with one Document library. And Approval Workflow Task is the Task list for the same workflow. And when i open the email 'Task assigned to userA on date is overdue' it gives me below error.

[image]

I checked in the Admin recycle bin but cant find the item. How do i stop users getting those unwanted emails.

Ok here is what i found in addition to above, The Collect Feedback was sent out to 10 Members and so creates 10 Approval Tasks for each member. And 8 out of 2 are not yet completed. And all 10 tasks as nowhere to be found in recycle bin.
So does that mean that just because those 2 tasks were left incomplete, it will still carry on sending users email of overdue items. If so how can i stop it?

Comment: Are you able to cancel or terminate workflow instance?

Comment: Basically there are no workflow currently running on those documents. And so i cant cancel or terminate workflow instance.  The issue that the collect feedback's Task List (Approval Workflow Task) where some tasks seems to be deleted as per the error. And not sure why emails are still being sent to the user about the due date.

Comment: I see. You can check this thread if it helps. Basically its all about old versions of workflow in this thread. You should look it once. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681413/how-to-stop-sharepoint-sending-task-overdue-emails-for-completed-and-deleted-tas

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case i dont see any previous versions of workflow that were left pending. Anyway i have updated my question with some additional information.

Comment: did you checked in all 3 recycle bins?

Comment: Hi, The Approval task list items were deleted months ago and cant get them from recycle bin. but now i am planning to do the restore content db to bring those tasks items back and terminate or cancel task, not sure it that works because alerts are still being sent to the users.